# I can use a declared property in implementation even without @synthesize it. Is this by design?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In the Hello World tutorial, I tried to comment out the '@synthesize userName = _userName;' in the HelloWorldViewController.m file. According to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1, "... You use the @synthesize directive to tell the compiler that it should synthesize the setter and/or getter methods for a property if you do not supply them within the @implementation block."

The strange thing to me is that even with '@synthesize userName = _userName;' commented out, the later appearance of statements in the HelloWorldViewController.m file, such as [self.userName length] and self.userName = [[self textField] text], is not considered to be an error or warning by Xcode (I am on V4.4.1). How is this possible?

As I understood, if @synthesize is missing for a declared property, the property is not even defined. What's more is no @synthesize means no getter or setter method for the property implemented. How come the Hello World app still compiles and runs perfect?

Part of code is here:

```
#import "HelloWorldViewController.h"
@implementation HelloWorldViewController
//@synthesize userName = _userName;
@synthesize label;
@synthesize textField;

...

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

[self setUserName:[[self textField] text]];

if([self.userName length]==0){
    [self setUserName: @"World"];
}
NSString *greeting=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", self.userName];
self.label.text=greeting;

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

self.userName = [[self textField] text];

if([self.userName length]==0){
    [self setUserName: @"World"];
}
NSString *greeting=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", self.userName];
self.label.text=greeting;

}

@end
```

Xcode gives no warning or error for the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Xcode 4.4 properties are automatically synthesized. If you declare a property that is readwrite and you don't implement the getter and the setter method for that property, Xcode will insert `@synthesize property = _property` automatically for you. For readonly properties you mustn't implement the getter method to get this behavior.

If you implement the setter and/or getter method Xcode will not synthesize the property automatically and won't create an iVar for you, either. In that case you can still add the `@synthesize` yourself.

Comment: I believe it's not the version of Xcode that matters, rather than the version (capabilities) of the underlying compiler, LLVM-clang.

Comment: You're right H2CO3, but I wanted to answer the question as simple as possible. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.4 there was a change whereby properties are synthesized by default. Therefore by omitting the synthesize yourself, the compiler does it for you!

[See Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/00-Introduction/Introduction.html) - specifically "The compiler automatically calls @synthesize by default for unimplemented @properties."

Comment: Thank you so much! This 'abnormal' xcode behavior provoke in me a lot confusion as this new feature is not updated in 'The Objective-C Programming Language' doc.